# How to connect Laravel to Firebase

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Laravel and Firebase. I need to connect Laravel to Firebase, but I am facing this error:

> Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Factory::getDatabase()

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $factory = (new Factory())
            ->withDatabaseUri('https://posts-ba088.firebaseio.com/');

        $datebase = $factory->getDatabase();

        $ref = $datebase->getReferece("Posts");

        $key = $ref->push()->getKey();

        return $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use createDatabase instead of getDatabase

```
$factory = (new Firebase\Factory());
$database  = $factory->createDatabase();
$ref = $datebase->getReference("Posts");
```

Read more here : [firebase-php](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/5.6.0/realtime-database.html)